# Mac OS tab switching in Eclipse-based IDEs

Tags: eclipse, macos

When I'm in Mac OS X, I'm able to switch tabs in my browsers and in TextMate using a Command- keybinding.  If I want to go to the first tab, I use Command-1, second tab Command-2, etc.

Is there a key binding in Eclipse based IDEs that will support this same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't support a tab-index-based navigation.  The default editor switch key binding as noted by other responders is CTRL+F6.  You can configure this to your liking (Window > Preferences > Keys: Next Editor).

Another way to switch between editors is to use CTRL+E.  This presents a dialog with all open editors.  You can type in the name of the one in which you are interested.  This comes in handy when you have numerous open editor tabs (and Eclipse has hidden tabs it is unable to show).

Answer (score 6):

While using eclipse on OSX, for switching tabs use the following shortcut

Ctrl + fn + Up Cursor Key for moving towards left tab

Ctrl + fn + Down Cursor Key for moving towards right tab

Here Ctrl is not Command, it is Ctrl just like other OS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as know the only way to switch between tabs in eclipse is **CTRL+F6** and **CTRL/PAGEUP**, **CTRL/PAGEDOWN** .

In OsX CTRL become CMD .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support the OSX based approach for a `TabFolder`, you will have to implement this yourself. E.g via an installed `KeyListener` on the tab folder.

If you want to implement this for the editors in the editor area of an Eclipse based IDE, you can do it via a new command with bindings for `M1+1` to `M1+9`... but... please note that `M1+1` is usually bound to "quick fix", `M1+2` is bound to "quick assist", `M1+3` is bound to "quick access", etc... So you will have a conflict...